# Action icons not showing Krajee File Input

Tags: javascript, plugins, icons

i'm using Krajee file input to make more friendly the uploading of files. Everything is working fine, except that the plugin does not show the action icons.

**actual view**

[image: actual view]

**My html code is this one**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/kartik-fileinput/fileinput.min.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/kartik-fileinput/fileinput-rtl.min.css')}}">
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="importar_excel">
        <input type="file" id="excel_in" name="empleados" required>
    </form>
    <script src="{{url('js/kartik-fileinput/fileinput.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url('js/kartik-fileinput/locales/LANG.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url('js/kartik-fileinput/locales/es.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

**My javascript code is this**

```
let input_file = document.querySelector('#excel_in');

if( input_file !== null){
    $("#excel_in").fileinput({
        language: "es",
        previewFileIconSettings: {
            'xlsx': '<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-brands-3/24/logo_brand_brands_logos_excel-512.png" class="file_icon">'
        },
        allowedFileExtensions: ["xlsx", "xls"]
    });
}
```

Comment: The network tab in developer tools shows everything was downloaded fine.